# How can i select id using angular.element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been trying to remove the DOM element using id. What will be the right way to do it in angular without using jquery, I have tried the following,

```
var element="sample";
angular.element('#'+element).remove();
```

Which seems not to be working. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't `angular.element` take a native JS element or a string of HTML and wrap it in jQuery? I don't think it's a selector engine ?

Comment: var ele = angular.element('#id').remove();

Comment: And one wonders why Angular sucks? Why not just `var el = document.getElementById('sample'); el.parentNode.removeChild(el);`

Answer (score 1):

The jquery lite version does not support selector so you need to pass a dom element reference to it.

```js
var element = "sample";
angular.element(document.getElementById(element)).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="sample">Should be deleted</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```js
var element = 'sample';
angular.element(document.getElementById(element)).remove();
// or 
// angular.element(document.querySelector('#' + element)).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="sample">Sample</div>
```